# Breakpoints not being hit with browser inspect for USB connected device

Tags: android, angular, debugging, ionic-framework, capacitor

While debugging my ionic capacitor application on the USB connected device, my browser dev-tools (Chrome, Edge, Firefox) is not hitting my breakpoints (debuggers in source code).

When I run it on ionic serve there is no problem.

I am not sure if it has to do anything with the source-map or symbols not being loaded.

Here is the warning massage in android studio:
"Attention! No symbol directories found - please check your native debug configuration".

I searched every related issue on source-maps but none of them were helpful because in most of those cases they are not loaded completely which is not the case here.
Also, last related issues where 2 years ago and angular-devtools are changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can check your angular.json file and see if you have some separate configurations for development or production build. You can check you default configuration if the build part under `defaultConfiguration`. Some of the tags you can look for under that configuration are `sourceMap: true`, `namedChunks: true` or `vendorChuck: true`.